# Why doesn't the function work with my input?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I have a default example dictionary which looks like this:

```
critics = {'Lisa Rose': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
'Just My Luck': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5,
'The Night Listener': 3.0},
           'Gene Seymour': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
'Just My Luck': 1.5, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5},
           'Michael Phillips': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.0,
'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'The Night Listener': 4.0},
'Claudia Puig': {'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5, 'Just My Luck': 3.0,
'The Night Listener': 4.5, 'Superman Returns': 4.0,
'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5},
           'Mick LaSalle': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,
'Just My Luck': 2.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0,
'You, Me and Dupree': 2.0},
'Jack Matthews': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,
'The Night Listener': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5},
           'Toby': {'Snakes on a Plane':4.5,'You, Me and Dupree':1.0,'Superman Returns':4.0}}
```

I use a function that returns the most similar person in the dictionary using the Pearson correlation coefficient which looks like this:

```
from math import sqrt
def sim_pearson(prefs,p1,p2):
# lista na zaednichki tochki
    si={}
    for item in prefs[p1]:
        if item in prefs[p2]: si[item]=1
# najdi go brojot na elementi
    n=len(si)
# ako nemaat zaednichki tochki vrati 0
    if n==0: return 0
# dodadi gi site
    sum1=sum([prefs[p1][it] for it in si])
    sum2=sum([prefs[p2][it] for it in si])
# sumiraj gi kvadratite
    sum1Sq=sum([pow(prefs[p1][it],2) for it in si])
    sum2Sq=sum([pow(prefs[p2][it],2) for it in si])
# sumiraj gi proizvodite
    pSum=sum([prefs[p1][it]*prefs[p2][it] for it in si])
# presmetka na Pirsonoviot koeficient
    num=pSum-(sum1*sum2/n)
    den=sqrt((sum1Sq-pow(sum1,2)/n)*(sum2Sq-pow(sum2,2)/n))
    if den==0: return 0
    r=num/den
    return r
```

and it works.  For example, for the call `print sim_pearson(critics, 'Toby', 'Lisa Rose')` I get the coefficient 0.991240707162.

However, when I try the same function with my dictionary which is:

```
tests = {'dzam': {'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiKAgw': 5.0,
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjvAQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj3AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiMAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiBAgw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjtAQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj_AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiIAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj9AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiqAgw': 3.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjzAQw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxikAgw': 3.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiaAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj1AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjxAQw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiYAgw': 5.0}, 
         'kex': {'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiKAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjvAQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj3AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiMAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiBAgw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjtAQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj_AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiIAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj9AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiqAgw': 3.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjzAQw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxikAgw': 3.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiaAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj1AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjxAQw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiYAgw': 5.0}, 
         'rokoko': {'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiKAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjvAQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj3AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiMAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiBAgw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjtAQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj_AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiIAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj9AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiqAgw': 3.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjzAQw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxikAgw': 3.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiaAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj1AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjxAQw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiYAgw': 5.0}, 
         'test@example.com': {'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiKAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjvAQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj3AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiMAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiBAgw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjtAQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj_AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiIAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj9AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiqAgw': 3.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjzAQw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxikAgw': 3.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiaAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxj1AQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjxAQw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiYAgw': 5.0}, 
         'seljak': {'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiKAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjvAQw': 1.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiKAgw': 5.0, 
'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxjvAQw': 1.0, }}
```

I always get 1.0, no matter that I have matches in the dictionaries, why is that so?

By the way, I'm using hashes so my dictionary MUST have this long strings. :)

Comment: Integers and division don't get along well together.  Please us `from __future__ import division` to see if that's the problem.

Comment: All your strings are the same in your failing test -- is that what you intended?  If so, that's why you're getting 1.0, indicating perfect correlation because everything's identical.

Comment: I have some differences, for example for the key 'ag1yYW5kb20tcmFuZG9tcg8LEghib29rbWFyaxiKAgw' there are fives and threes.

Comment: I tried with the import division from future and the results are the same.

Comment: Totally unrelated to the question, but I don't understand why you need those long strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably fooled by the long keys that hide to the eyes which strings are different.

Try setting all the values to `0` in test `'seljak'` and run a correlation with it. You'll see a `0` correlation:

```
print sim_pearson(tests, 'test@example.com', 'seljak')
```

Change the last value of test `'seljak'` to 1 and you will see a negative correlation re-running the script.

Comment: mhm.. it's okey with the function.. I have the same answers everytime because the reading from my database and forming this dictionary is wrong.